# Supported graphics card: AMD Radeon HD 4250 GPU?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is the AMD Radeon HD 4250 GPU supported for Gazebo under Ubuntu?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3292/supported-graphics-card:-amd-radeon-hd-4250-gpu?/) by [John Nagle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/395/john-nagle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We currently recommend using nvidia graphic cards. I haven't tried the card you mentioned.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0